# Migrating a table from Access to SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access

I have a particular table in access which I am trying to migrate it to SQL Server, the problem is that I am trying to create a table in sql server with the required fields and there are around 200 variables. Hence I am trying to find out if there is any easy way of copying the access data type in the sql server migration assistant.

If not I will have to manually type in the access data type in the create table sql query.

Comment: Why not use the Migration Wizard thats part of the Migration Assistant? http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh313045.aspx

Answer (score 1):

For moving tables from Access to SQL Server, I have had good luck with the **SQL Server Upsizing Wizard** that's built into Access itself:

[image: upsize.png]

For detailed instructions on how to use it, check the following link

[Use the Upsizing Wizard - Access - Office.com](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/use-the-upsizing-wizard-HP005273009.aspx)